# how to stop OneDrive searches appearing in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, search, onedrive-for-business

Currently we have a tenancy we use in the university where both staff and students reside. Currently when a staff member searches on SharePoint in the search results it brings back OneDrive results is there a way of stopping OneDrive results from appearing in the results.

Comment: Do you want to exclude only the users OneDrive or all OneDrive results? Also...why?